# arecord out files have no sound in ordinary players

Tags: sound, alsa

I have just made some recordings with `arecord`. I can play them as expected with `aplay`, but when I play them on SMPlayer or VLC media player or Videos, I get no sound out. (The progress ticker moves forward for the duration of the playback; there's just nothing audible.)

I do my recording as follows:

```
arecord -f "cd" -D plughw:2,0 -d 2 -r 48000 -t wav -c 2 "test.wav"
```

Can anyone see how I should troubleshoot or understand this matter? Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess SMPlayer/VLC use PulseAudio. Try `pavucontrol`.

Comment: Tested the command line here: worked well and played back with vlc and SMPlayer fine. Seems odd...